# Access object data from an exported javascript file in react Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, object

I am working on a project in react native where i need to access data
stored in another file {users} as js object this is my sample data

```
export var ibpid = {
    name:'Dave',
    
}
```

i have imported the data in another file using this syntax

`import * as ibpid from './YearSwitch'`

if i access the data ibpid an object if i log it i get the folowing

```
  "ibpid": Object {
    "name": "samuel",
  },
}
```

but if i try to access the object child name i get undefined.
Is there something i am missing.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you show how you are accessing the name property

Comment: i have tried to use `ibpid.name`

Comment: can you show the full code?  That should work